# Concatenate multiple databags on a recipe chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, databags

I am trying to concatenate multiple databags into a single array :

```
jettyrealm_prop=[]
data_bag_item('data_' + node.chef_environment, node['product']['realm_databag'].each do |item|
jettyrealm_prop.insert(item)
end)
```

node['product']['realm_databag'] added into attributes

but this provides this error :

> [2018-09-20T10:51:49+02:00] ERROR: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Comment: Can you try to run this code `node['product']['realm_databag'].each do |item| jettyrealm_prop.insert(item) end` alone and find out if it throws an error or not!

Comment: it throws no errors !

Comment: Then the error is not in this code, it's inside the `data_bag_item` method. your code/question is not comprehensive enough to help us understand what's happening. Could you paste at least the stack printout for the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = node['product']['realm_databag'].map |item|
  data_bag_item('data_' + node.chef_environment, item)
end
```

This should work and it's more elegant!

Answer (score 0):

```
jettyrealm_prop=[]
node['product']['realm_databag'].each do |item|
  jettyrealm_prop.push(item)
end

tab=[]
jettyrealm_prop.each do |item1|
  tab=data_bag_item('data_' + node.chef_environment, item1)
end
```

I splitted the ressource bloc and it works ...

Comment: Why you move `node['product']['realm_databag']` to `jettyrealm_prop` and then reiterate over it? it's an unnecessary extra step! Look at my solution :) Please, upvote it if it did work for you.